# How To Get Wordpress User ID From External PHP Script?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to validate WooCommerce subscriptions and I need the userid to do it but it keeps returning 0 from $current_user->ID.

```
<?php
include('../wp-load.php');
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$SubCheck = WC_Subscriptions_Manager::user_has_subscription( $current_user->ID, 9, 'active' );
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way,**why $current_user->ID**

```
<?php $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); ?> 

Returns (int) 
The user's ID, if there is a current user; otherwise 0.
```

SEE:http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

**EDIT2:**

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID;
?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php 
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->ID 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

thy this...

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->ID
```

Comment: more explanation would make this a better answer